# gradle exclude resource file only when building jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have `dev.conf` file in `src/main/resources` folder which is relevant only for running projects locally from IDE. When running `gradlew build docker` I would like to exclude this `dev.conf` file from jar. My build.gradle looks like that:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.7.3'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.34.0'
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.4.1"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.11


def versions = [
        ScalaBinary: "2.13",
        akkaVersion: "2.6.19",
        lightbendVersion: "1.1.3",
        SlickVersion: "3.3.3"
]

group 'com.vanilla'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
       ...
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


jar{
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-class': 'com.vanilla.Application'
    }

}


springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

sourceSets {
     main {
        resources {
            exclude '**/dev.conf'
          }
     }
}
//docker configuration to follow.
```

However, after adding `exclude` closure, my `dev.conf` excluded in every task including running from intellij. How can I exclude this file only while building jar and creating docker from it.